# How to save a data to Realtime database in Firebase in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to save  just an object to Realtime Database in Firebase, but it is not responding at all. I want to send a chatroom object to the child chatrooms.

[This is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLSld.png)

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation?

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: Yes, I tried to attach the listener. In this particular project, I can't save data. But, when I created a new project for the same firebase application, I was able to do send an ojbect.

Comment: So you added a listener, did you get some message indicating that something went wrong? Please also edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.